# Laravel : BadMethodCallException Method [find] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

when trying to extract some values from the database using the model object User I get the following error : `BadMethodCallException Method [find] does not exist`

Here are my files : 
Model User

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

        public function projects()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Project');
        }

        public function trys()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Try');
        }

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

Controller user :

```
<?php

class user extends BaseController {


    public function showWelcome($id)
    {
        $user1 = User::find($id);
        return View::make('users.index', array('user' => $user1)); //
    }

}
```

View users/index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>first page</title>

</head>
<body>
    <?php echo 'Hello'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and the routes.php :

```
<?php
Route::get('user/{id}', 'user@showWelcome');
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: isn't it already implemented in the Eloquent parent class ?

Comment: You have a find() method called in one of your ServiceProviders, possibly the ViewServiceProvider.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should not get this error, because it seems like you are using Eloquent and there is a `find()` method on it.

But you are getting this error and there are some possible reasons:

1) The `User::` you are calling is not the same you are showing here, to check execute in your controller:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass("User");
$fn = $reflector->getFileName();
dd($fn);
```

It must show you the full path of your class.

2) There's is something wrong with autoloading, you can run:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

To try to fix it.

3) There is something wrong with Laravel sources, you can delete Laravel code:

```
rm -rf vendor/laravel
```

and install it again

```
composer update
```

Comment: I tried the 3 options none of them worked, with option 1 I got : Class \ConsultorioDigital\Models\VocalUser\Model does not exist

Comment: Sorry that was my class name, I was doing a test with it here and forgot to edit. Change it to `User`, of course.

Comment: It showed me a wrong file name : string(48) "/mylaravelapp/app/controllers/user.php"

Comment: It seems there is a conflict between the model class User.php and the controller class user.php, I solved it by chaging the controller class  name to UserController. Thank you Carlos

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes this conflict is caused when another model of the same name exists in Laravel and most likely has a precedence over your model. Avoid "Key Words". For me, my problem was calling my model: **Form** and my db table (from a migration): **forms**.

Running the following cmd in my **FormController**:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass("Form");
$fn = $reflector->getFileName();
dd($fn);
```

showed me that the "real" **Form** was located in the Illuminate framework:

```
"/home/pkanane/laravel_appz/cpay/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Form.php"
```

So I just changed my model name to **WebForm** and my db table to **web_forms**

Comment: I am using a model named Form and a table named forms and encountered this exact same issue, I am changing my model and table names now. Crazyy