# Laravel User relations stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship

I just downloaded and started a new project with the latest Laravel 4.2.

My problem is in the `User` model if I define any relation it's not working.

**User Model**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


    public function metadata()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Metadata');
    }


    public function test()
    {
        return "hello test";
    }

}
```

**Metadata Model**

```
class Metadata extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    protected $table = "users_metadata";

    protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name');

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

So if I do this

```
$user =  User::find(1);

dd($user->metadata);
```

I get back `Null`, and above i made a test method in my `User` model

If I do this:

```
$user =  User::find(1);

dd($user->test());
```

I get

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::test()
```

Why? It's clearly there. I put my code in an earlier version and it worked fine.

And what really confuses me is that if I do this:

```
$metadata =  Metadata::find(1);

dd($metadata->user);
```

It works fine with the `belongsTo` method, I tested `User` model with another relation - same results.

Comment: You say it's `Users` model while the class is called `User` - let's start with that. Now, the thing is, you are calling another class, so check the reflection to trace that class (file).

Comment: sorry, typo, i call it User, but the i accidentally said Users in my question, as i mentioned, the User model relations do not work but the other class models do work, (corrected the typo), and as i mentioned, with earlier version of laravel worked, (4.0)

Comment: you may need to specify the foreign key, as you appear to be using `user_id` and not `id` which is what laravel defaults to. Something like `return $this->hasOne('Metadata', 'user_id');`

Comment: that cannot be the problem, as i mentioned, non relations, work, not even single functions work in it

Comment: use this answer to find out what class is loaded when you call `User`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882347/laravel-badmethodcallexception-method-find-does-not-exist#answer-22882766

Comment: It may be that Laravel doesn't like that you setting the `$primaryKey` for the Meteadata model as `user_id` which is technically the foreign key . The table should have it's own primary key (usually `id`) that auto increments, I think this is a requirement of eloquent.

Comment: First thanks for the time and effort what you pushed to answer my questions. I quit laravel, i had it with it when a new version comes out its always has problems, and a pain in the butt to upgrade, i will just recode my app with another framework, no matter what i do, everything else works, all models work, just the User model, all problems started when i did composer update to get a new package of intervention image class, since than not even a fresh install or no updated versions do not work, no matter what i do. Still thanks for the time and effort, wish you all a great day

Comment: Dont get upset so fast, as the way i see, since the User model does not showing the actual method or function what you defined, its because, somewhere else there is another User model defined, trust me check it. And it will be fine after you remove the duplicate

Comment: Wow, you where right, i had an User model in my Auth folder as well, tans so much, really, great catch

Comment: [This problem solved][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669789/default-user-model-throws-error-in-laravel

Laravel 4.2